# SQL Server Error 208: Invalid object name 'Utils.dbo.ChangeLogging_DDLCommands'

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures

When trying to change the user account to link with the `NewMary` login:

```
EXEC sp_change_users_login 'Update_One', 'Mary', 'NewMary'
go
```

I get the error 208:

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Procedure ChangeLogging_LogDDLCommands, Line 147
>   Invalid object name 'Utils.dbo.ChangeLogging_DDLCommands'.

I don't find any relevant information on `ChangeLogging_DDLCommands`, and I'm lost at how I do have to proceed from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you have some kind of custom trigger, which is missing this object.

In SSMS:

- Check server triggers under "Server Objects" > "Triggers"
- Check individual database DDL triggers under "Programmability" -> "Database triggers"

Comment: Never thought it was a local problem -- working on a client database...

Comment: @Bridge Thanks a lot, I was stuck with SQL Server 2016. I manage to find my issue which was located under the Triggers. I had to delete the disturbing trigger to be able to resolve this problem. Thanks a million